# An "inner isodiametric inequality"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

To set the stage, let me recall the well-known *isodiametric inequality*, which states that 
$$
\mathcal L^n(A)\le\frac{\alpha(n)}{2^n}(\operatorname{diam} A)^n
$$
for every set $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, where $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$.

Clearly, the converse inequality does not hold, since one can easily figure out a sequence of sets with constant Lebesgue measure whose diameters blow up. On the other hand, if one considers the "*inner diameter*" of $A$:
$$
\underline{\operatorname{diam}}A:=2\sup_{x\in A}\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial A),
$$
then one should be able to prove the following "*inner isodiametric inequality*":
$$
(*)\quad\quad \frac{\alpha(n)}{2^n}(\underline{\operatorname{diam}} A)^n\le \mathcal L^n(A).
$$
In fact, the left-hand side of (*) is the volume of the largest ball included in $A$.

**Now my question.** I have a set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$. Given $A\subseteq \Omega$, I define the *relative inner diameter* of  $A$ with respect to $\Omega$ as follows:
$$
\underline{\operatorname{diam}}_{\Omega} A:=2\sup_{x\in A}\operatorname{dist}(x,\overline{\Omega\setminus A}).
$$
What I am after is a bound similar to (*), but with $\underline{\operatorname{dist}} A$ replaced by $\underline{\operatorname{dist}}_\Omega A$. Intuition suggests that there exists some $\delta_\Omega$ such that the following implication holds true:
$$
\mathcal L^n(A)\le\delta_\Omega\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{\alpha(n)}{2^n}(\underline{\operatorname{diam}}_{\Omega} A)^n\le \mathcal L^n(A). 
$$
However, I am quite sure that one needs to ask something on $\Omega$ (if $\Omega$ has a cusp then I can easily imagine a counterexample). Perhaps the segment property (as in Adams' book) will do?

Thanks in advance for your help.